# Show text in a DIV instead of HREF title tag, for Jquery onhover

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently we have this:

```
<a href="#" title="Message here" style="color:#333; margin:0px; padding:0px; float:left;">
    <div style="float:left; margin:5px 0 0 20px; padding:0px; width:155px;"  id="show-option" >
        <div style="float:left; margin:0px 0 0 0px; padding:0px;">
            <img src="block-1.png"/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; margin:5px 0 0 12px; padding:0px; font-size: 12px;">
            Our Promise
        </div>     
    </div>
</a>
```

I won't provide the rest of the code but when 'Our Promise' is hovered over above, jquery is utilised to show some text.

The downside with the code above is the onhover text is defined by:

```
title="Message here"
```

This does not allow us to put images and have some text bolded etc for the onhover message. So I am thinking we need 'Message here' text to be in a DIV so that we can style to our heart's content.

What would be the best way to do this please? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are a few prebuild solutions for a modal window.You may take a look at http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Tooltip.
It is very easy.

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/